# <title></title> tag occurs two time on Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have set the Page title dynamically. When I look the page source in that the `<title>` tag occurs two time, one tag have the value which I have set dynamically just below the `<head>` start, but another is blank just before the `</head>`.
In  master page head tag contains below code:

```
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="pageTitle" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">       
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

on Page I have set the Page title like:

```
 var title = new HtmlTitle {Text = title1};
  var h1Tag = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(this, "pageTitle");// by the find the pageTitle control 
   if (h1Tag != null)
   {
      h1Tag.Controls.Add(title);
    }
```

I am not able to figure out why the title occurs twice.
I also want to put metakeyword,metadescription and title just below the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

ASP .Net also sets(adds) the title of the page, even there is no value. Try to use `Page.Title` to dynamically set the title.

Comment: I have tried this but it add the <title> </title> tag just before the closing head tag. but I want <title> </title> just below the opening head tag.

Comment: This behavior is odd, are sure about this?

Comment: yes, I got the Solutions for that. Just add the default <title>test</title> on master page any position where you want to place, just reset that on page where you want to set dynamically.